# How to use multiple re.compile () for grepping and matching all patterns in a file

Tags: python, regex

Actually i have an array and i have 10 pattern need to match inside the array. I have used 10 re.compile() and 10 if statement to match the pattern in an array. Could you please help me to optimize the code. I couldn`t paste the original code as a there was some issue. But please fine the sample code

```
import re
pattern1 = re.compile("Pattern1")
pattern2 = re.compile("Pattern2")
pattern3 = re.compile("Pattern3")
pattern4 = re.compile("Pattern4")
pattern5 = re.compile("Pattern5")
pattern6 = re.compile("Pattern6")
pattern7 = re.compile("Pattern7")
pattern8 = re.compile("Pattern8")
pattern9 = re.compile("Pattern9")
pattern10 = re.compile("Pattern10")
variable = [element1,element2,...,elementN]
for line in variable:
    if (re.search(pattern1,line)):
        printf("Pattern1 match found")
    if ...
    if ...
    if ...
    ...
```

Comment: depending on your exact use case, you could use a single regex

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor your code to use containers:

```
patterns = ['Pattern1', 'Pattern2', 'Pattern3']
regexes = {p: re.compile(p) for p in patterns}

for line in variable:
    for pat, regex in regexes.items():
        if re.search(regex, line):
            print(f'{pat} match found')
```